# While loop not... whileing

Tags: python, while-loop

```
sticks = int(27)
player1 = True
player2 = True

if sticks > 0:
    while player1 == True:
        player1sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2 or 3"))
        sticks = sticks - player1sticks
        player1 = False
        player2 = False
                            
    while player2 == False:
        player2sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2, or 3"))
        sticks = sticks - player2sticks
        player1 = True
        player2= True
else:
    print("END")
```

Why doesnt this work?
I need the program to run back and forth between the two players until there are 0 (or less) sticks,
Python 3.8.5

Comment: `I need the program to run back and forth between the two players until there are 0 (or less) sticks` You should've used `while sticks > 0` then.

Comment: And the inner `while` loops look like they should be `if`s instead since they'll never loop.

Comment: Change `if sticks > 0` to `while sticks > 0`.   Your program will still have the bug that if player1 takes all the sticks, then it'll still be player2's turn after that.

Comment: Thanks although now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the loop while like this

```
sticks = int(27)


while sticks > 0:
    if sticks > 0
        player1sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2 or 3"))
        sticks = sticks - player1sticks                       
    if sticks > 0
        player2sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2, or 3"))
        sticks = sticks - player2sticks  
else:
    print("END")
```

EDIT: the first IF it's not necessary.

```
sticks = int(27)


while sticks > 0:
    player1sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2 or 3"))
    sticks = sticks - player1sticks                       
    if sticks > 0
        player2sticks = int(input("Take a stick(s), 1, 2, or 3"))
        sticks = sticks - player2sticks  
else:
    print("END")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `while sticks > 0`
2. You don't need while inside loop — you can just put blocks for player 1 and 2 one after another (and check if `sticks == 0` for second)